# Dynamic Neighborhood Coordinates

Tags: c#, coordinates, generator, points

For an image filter I want to generate a variable neighborhood.
This is how my neighborhood looks like at the moment, it's a moore neighborhood.

```
private Point[] neighborhood = new Point[]
                                               {
                                                   new Point(-1,-1),
                                                   new Point(0,-1),
                                                   new Point(1,-1),

                                                   new Point(-1,0),
                                                   new Point(1,0),

                                                   new Point(-1,1), 
                                                   new Point(0,1), 
                                                   new Point(1,1), 
                                               };
```

When I want to change the size of the neighborhood this can become quite complicated.
I want a funktion that returns all coordinates, like generateNeighborhood(8) would return this array of Points. Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private Point[] GetNeighbors(int count)
{
    int a, x, y, c = count / 2;
    Point[] p = new Point[count * count];

    for (a = y = 0; y < count; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
            p[a++] = /* Create point here */
    return p;
}
```

*I think you can add the missing piece of code* ;)

Comment: why do you use: int a, x, y, c = count / 2;?

Comment: Variable **c** represents the center coordinate, so you calculate the difference (delta) between the current coordinate and de center ;)

Comment: I do this later when I need the coordinates.  for (a= y = 0; y < count; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
                {
                    if (!(x == 0 && y == 0))
                    {
                    
                    p[a++] = new Point(x, y);
                    p[a++] = new Point(-1*x, -1*y);
                }
            }
            }
            return p; } works great :) thank you

Comment: Actually the comment should be replaced simply with `new Point(x - c, y - c);`, that's all!